# You can run shell script using Applet Java?

Tags: java, linux, shell, printing, applet

I have an web application that needs to print ZPL codes on a thermal printer using Java Applet. I've found two ways to print on linux.
First: create a file and send it to the printer, however, according to what I found researching, Java blocks editing and reading local files with Applet, for security reasons. Therefore dismissed the possibility.
Second: without having to create a file and send it to the printer, was to use the following shell script:

```
lpr -P "Thermal Printer" -l <<< "^XA^MNN^JMA^FS^LT120^FO160,125^ADN,20,20^FD ^FS^PQ1^XZ";
```

The command works perfectly directly in the terminal, but when I'm trying to use the applet, it does not perform.

I'm trying to perform printing as follows:

```
    String command = "lpr -P \"" + printer.getName () + "\" -l <<< \"" + zpl + " \"";
    ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("/ bin / bash");
    commands.add("- c");
    commands.add(command);

    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    Process pr = p.start ();
    pr.waitFor ();
```

I've read that I can't do what I want, but I don't see another way to do that.

Does anyone have any idea what can be?

Thanks You.

Comment: Just have the user accept permissions so you app isnt sandboxed. See privileged applets: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: I've signed my applet and add the certificate into Certificates of Java Control Panel, but, even allowing the running of applet into client, I had that error: **acces denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/bin/bash" "execute")**. Know why?

Comment: Did you set the correct security permissions?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/security.html - Check out the security tag

Comment: I had forgot `<security> <all-permissions/> </security>` in JNLP file. When I put this, the Java Security blocked my applet. Any ideia again? :S. Thanks for all

Comment: Can you post a pick of that? I think I know what your talking about, but need to make sure.

Comment: In my manifest, I had **Permissions: sandbox**. I corrected to **Permissions: all-permissions** and the problem of access denied come back again

Comment: I try to execute the browser as root, but he blocked the Applet with this message as _Reason_: **Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running**

Comment: I found the problem. My java.policy is blocking everything. I change this and my Applet works fine :D. I'll try to understand how to configure to grant only for my URL, but now it's another problem, hehe. Thank you very much by the help